# Python - Textwrapping questions and answers in list within a quiz

Tags: python, word-wrap

I've created a multiple choice quiz in Python. I want to textwrap questions and answers while otherwise maintaining the multi-line format. Attempts to wrap the text below have resulted in answers being merged or the following error: "attributeerror 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'"

```
import random
import time
import textwrap
class Question:
     def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
          self.prompt = prompt
          self.answer = answer
     
question_prompts = [
#Question 0
     "Question with so many words that not everything can fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap:\
     \na. Short answer\
     \nb. Medium answer\
     \nc. Answer with so many words that not everything can fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap\
     \nd. Answer\n",
#Question 1
     "What question is this?:\n\
     \na. Question 1\
     \nb. Completely irrelevant answer that is so long it cannot fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap\
     \nc. Not the right answer\
     \nd. Question 10\n"]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "c"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "b")]

def run_quiz(questions):
     score = 0
     start_time = time.time()
     end_time = time.time() - start_time
     minutes = end_time/60
     seconds = end_time % 60
     random.shuffle(questions)
     textwrap.fill(question, 30)
     for question in questions:
          response = input(question.prompt)
          correct = question.answer
          elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
          if response == question.answer:
            print("Correct!\n")
            score += 1
          else:
              print("The correct answer is", correct, "\n")
     print("You scored", round(score/len(questions)*100, 1), "% correct")
     print("Quiz completed in", int(minutes), "minute(s) and", int(seconds), "second(s)")

run_quiz(questions)
```

Comment: I posted an answer guessing that you were asking about wrapping the source code.  You responded that you were asking about wrapping the output.  That is more complicated.  Often, though maybe not always, software emulating a terminal will automatically wrap text onto a following line.  This might be ugly, breaking a word in the middle.  To get a useful answer, you should provide more information, such as:  How do the long lines look now?  Do they wrap, but break at places you don't like?  Do you know the line width the terminal will support at run time?  Will just inserting newlines fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Currently, text wrapping breaks the word down with remaining characters on the next line. This can be fixed by increasing the terminal width, but I want to keep the terminal width the same and have entire words wrap. Inserting newlines will fix it, but is there a way to automatically format the long lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module of the standard library.

Example:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = textwrap.fill("Question with so many words that not everything can fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap:")
>>> s
'Question with so many words that not everything can fit on a single\nline, requiring a textwrap:'
>>> print(s)
Question with so many words that not everything can fit on a single
line, requiring a textwrap:
```

The default line width is 70 characters, but you can change it.

For a long line in the middle of the string, you can break the string into pieces, wrap the long piece, and concatenate the pieces:

```
#Question 1
     "What question is this?:\n\
     \na. Question 1\n" +
     textwrap.fill("b. Completely irrelevant answer that is so long it cannot fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap") +
     "\nc. Not the right answer\
     \nd. Question 10\n"]
```

The `textwrap.fill` call got rid of the initial newline character on the long line, so I added it to the end of the preceding string.

By default, `textwrap.fill` will replace whitespace characters, including newlines, with space characters before wrapping.  If you don't want it to do that, pass it the keyword parameter `replace_whitespace=False`.

By default, `textwrap.fill` will also remove whitespace at the beginning and end of every line after wrapping.  This doesn't seem to apply to newlines except those at the end of the wrapped text.  If you don't want it to do that, pass it the keyword parameter `drop_whitespace=False`.

Comment: For question 1 answer b, how would I escape out of the quotes to textwrap?

Comment: When trying to wrap a question and answers, they're formatted into a single line.

`textwrap.fill("What question is this?:\n") +

     textwrap.fill("a. Question 1\n") +

     textwrap.fill("b. Completely irrelevant answer that is so long it cannot fit on a single line, requiring a textwrap\n") +

     textwrap.fill("c. Not the right answer\
     \nd. Question 10\n"]`

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to tell `textwrap.fill` to leave your newlines alone.  You could also just not call it for short lines you want to stay as separate lines.